# activemodel return json with associated model data

Tags: activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord, activemodel

in rails 4, I can not figure out how to fetch model and associated models together.

For example, I have a User model which has_many Message

The following code work properly.

```
@user = User.find 29, include: :messages
@messages = @user.messages
```

However, when I try to return @user with @messages in json

```
render :json @user
```

The returned result does not contain @messages, only the @user data is returned.

One workaround I can do is to construct a hash with

```
{user: @user, messages: @messages}
```

But the problem is messages are not nested or associated to user.

Is there a activemodel/activerecord buildin method to render associated data in a easier way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as always, the documentation on the rails side is pretty bad. what you need to do is call either call `to_json` with options or override the models `to_json` method: http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Serialization/to_json

Comment: Thank you. I did not know to_json has those options to set.